# Weird destructuring behavior in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, destructuring

I have a deeply nested JSON object as state initially made with useState hook -

```js
 const [template, setTemplate] = useState([
    {
      
      statement: 'this is top level statement',
      nestingLevel: 0,
      children: [
        {
          nestingLevel: 1,
          statement:
            'this is a statement with such a template',
          children: [
            { 
              statement: 'first chart',
              nestingLevel: 2,
            },
            { statement: 'second chart',
              nestingLevel: 2,
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
    {
     
      statement:
        'this is second statement for section with such a metric {{}}',
      nestingLevel: 0,
      
    },
  ]);
```

I have an input element with an onChange handler.

As you can see, whenever there is some change in the input text, I update some relevant key-value pair based on path. I do so by using the lodash library's get and set functions.

```js
 const handleDataChange = (e, path) => {
        console.log('handling the data');
        // copy the template
        let templateCopy = template;
        // create the new object with updated information
        const tempObj = _.set(
          templateCopy,
          `${path}['statement']`,
          e.target.value,
        );

        setTemplate([...tempObj]);
      };
```

The problem is in the handleDataChange function. When I do `setTemplate(tempObj)` the state doesn't get updated. However when I do `setTemplate([...tempObj])`(which will essentially yield the same result), this later solution works as expected.

I want to know why that is the case. Is it because lodash gives results always as object and destructuring and repacking it make it array again and hence it works as expected?

Comment: "*// create the new object with updated information*" this is not correct, `_.set` will *mutate* the object passed into it and also return it. `tempObj` is the same object as `templateCopy`. And `templateCopy` is already the same object as `template`. There are no copies in that function.

Comment: consider using https://github.com/immerjs/immer for such updates

Comment: @VLAZ thanks for pointing it out. What is the best way to go about it when using lodash functions? I can test and let you know if it works. Also, why is the destructing solution working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object reference stays the same when you mutate nested property only, and as react does shallow comparison in order to detect changes, it won't react to the change.

You can `deepClone` the object, then mutate it as you do with `set` and then update the state.

Comment: Lodash has a [cloneDeep() function](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep) for just that. Thanks for pointing it out. Works as expected without that extra destructuring and wrapping in array workaround.